# discord.py kick command it not working somehow please help me T-T

Tags: python

I don't have much knowledge on Python, and still in the process of learning it.

I have been significantly modifying an open-source Discord bot coded in Python 2.7.

I would like to add a feature that allows me to kick a user based on a command.

Something like [commandprefix]kickuser [userid] But I have no idea how to make the bot grab the userid from the message I sent, and when I try to make it ultra-specific to kick my second account as a test, it doesn't work either...

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=')

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, userName: discord.User):
  await bot.kick(userName) 
    
@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send(f"Sorry you don't have permission to do that")
bot.run("token")```
**no error** *no work*
````

Comment: It seems like you have to pass a discord.Member (which is a subclass of discord.User) instead of discord.User.

Comment: nah bro still not working

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: no error message it just not working

Comment: Well yeah you dont have an error because you're catching them all in that custom error handler and only doing something for MissingPermissions. You explicitly don't do anything at all for other errors. Re-raise the exception (or print it yourself) if you want to see the other types of exceptions.